# django get default value from database stored procedure

Tags: database, django, postgresql

Is there any way I can set the auto field id of a django model to pick its value from 
a database procedure. for example:

```
class Service(models.Model):

id = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, default=database_procedure)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
icon = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='iconset-info.png')
description = models.TextField()
```

and the database procedure is something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION database_procedure() RETURNS trigger AS $database_procedure$
    BEGIN
       [...]
    END;
$database_procedure$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Your update to the question changed it substantially, making my answer seem partially OT. *Please don't do that.* Also, your function definition is now syntactical nonsense, since the `RETURNS` clause requires a data type.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter sorry for the mishap. I only intended to demonstrate the question. I won't change it again and appreciate your answer below.

Comment: I rolled back to the previous version accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any function in a default value expression, including your own - as long as it returns a suitable **data type**. [The manual specifies](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html):

> `DEFAULT` **default_expr**
>
> The `DEFAULT` clause assigns a default data value for the column whose column definition it appears within. The value is any
>   variable-free expression (subqueries and cross-references to other
>   columns in the current table are not allowed). The data type of the
>   default expression **must match the data type of the column**.

Bold emphasis mine.
But the function you display is a trigger function (`RETURNS trigger`) and **cannot** be used for that.

If your function returns `varchar` or any other type that can be coerced to the type of the column, you can use it. Should simply be `default=myfunc()` in Django. It's `DEFAULT myfunc()` in `CREATE TABLE` of SQL. Including the parentheses, empty in my example for a function without parameters.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. so for the procedure from a database how do I set it to pick the default value from the procedure? I am trying to avoid going to the database twice.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use just as you want?

[Default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default) value may be callable object. Therefore, in a function you can turn to the database and do something.

Also [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/signals/) may be helpful for you.

Comment: Because it's a trigger function.